# Combinations and paritioning

Tags: probability

Nine workers are assigned to nine jobs. Two of the jobs are considered bad, four are considered average, and three of the jobs are considered good. The 9 workers consist of seven men and two women. If workers are randomly assigned to jobs, calculate the probability that the two women are assigned to both bad jobs.

This is right after the introduction to combinations and partitioning. I figured there was {9 \choose 2} ways of splitting picking the workers, and {9 \choose 2,4,3} ways to pick the jobs. but this fractions gives me an answer of .0286 and the correct answer is .02778.

I'm really not sure where to start or what logic to use, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Your general procedure, though not optimal, will work. However, if you use $\binom{9}{2,4,3}$ to count the number of ways to assign the jobs, then the number of "favourables" is $\binom{2}{2}\binom{7}{4,3}$. Of course $\binom{7}{4,3}$ can be more simply written as $\binom{7}{4}$. Simplification of the fraction yields $\frac{1}{36}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't worry about what jobs are left for the other workers; just count about ways to pick jobs to give to the women.

There are two women to give jobs to, two bad jobs, and nine jobs in total.

There are $\binom{2}{2}$ ways to pick both bad jobs.

There are $\binom{9}{2}$ ways to pick any two jobs.

Hence the probability of picking bad jobs for both women is:$$\dfrac{1}{\binom{9}{2}}=\frac 1{36} = 0.0277\dot{7}$$

Comment: the answer in the book is 10 times smaller than this. Do you think it's a mistake in the solutions, or is there something else to be considered? Thank you for your help.

Comment: @AlbertWolfgang Typgraphical errr. Missed a zer.  Crrected.